# Laravel 5.7 post-install-cmd

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

I use Laravel 5.7 and would like to install a new Laravel project with the `laravel new` command.

```
laravel new myproject
```

After running this command I get the following error:

> [InvalidArgumentException] Script "post-install-cmd" is not defined in
>   this package
>
> run-script [--timeout TIMEOUT] [--dev] [--no-dev] [-l|--list] [--][][]...

Any ideas?

Comment: I would bet you need to upgrade the `laravel/installer` package. Or, you could try `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel myproject` (which is what `laravel new` executes under the hood).

Answer (score 0):

You should try first:
composer global update
In order to update Laravel installer. If for some reason that fails, I would try using composer to create new project. Docs are [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/installation).

Answer (score 0):

composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel myproject "5.7.*"

Answer (score -1):

You could use:
`composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel myproject`